# ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, psutil

I recently started working with Docker but I was trying to  build Docker Images for a Flask App, I run into the following error :

Failed to build cffi kiwisolver Pillow psutil
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1

It is caused by the line

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

in my Dockerfile as far as I can tell.

I tried searching for a solution and what I found so far was:
-checking the spelling of the docker file (Dockerfile) since it's case sensitive
-export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0
in the terminal but export isn't recognised as a command
-updated pip
-install packages with pip install

I tried all I could find on the internet,sadly nothing worked.

I must also mention I'm working on windows

Answer (score 0):

You should install gcc and python3-dev with apt (if you are on a python or ubuntu base image).

Try something like:

```
FROM python:3.11.3-slim

# Install all OS dependencies for fully functional requirements.txt install
RUN apt-get update --yes && \
    apt-get upgrade --yes && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    # - apt-get upgrade is run to patch known vulnerabilities in apt-get packages as
    #   the python base image may be rebuilt too seldom sometimes (less than once a month)
    # required for psutil python package to install
    python3-dev \
    gcc && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

I've added extra commands I think you should consider:

- updating apt cache and upgrading apt packages
- install apt package with `--no-install-recommends` for a smaller image
- cleaning up after apt for a smaller image
- not caching pip installs during `pip install`

p.s. I tried to install gcc and python3-dev after finding [issue #2192 on psutil's github](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/2192#issuecomment-1396079848) via a duck duck go search for [the error I saw during my docker build](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=docker+apt+Building+wheel+for+psutil+(pyproject.toml)+did+not+run+successfully.&ia=web).